# Initialize Dictionary<string,string> from List<string>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, extension-methods

Easiest way to do this, perhaps from an extension method? :

```
var MyDic = new Dictionary<string,string>{ "key1", "val1", "key2", "val2", ...};
```

Where the dictionary winds up with entries contain key and value pairs from the simple list of strings, alternating every other string being the key and values.

Comment: What do you want to happen when a key is `null` or two keys are equal or the list has an odd length? Handling these issues will shape the code.

Comment: in my case, it expects non-null and unique keys. Since I wouldn't try to use those as keys normally, and this is just a shorthand method

Answer (score 10):

The alternation is a bit of a pain. *Personally* I'd just do it longhand:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index += 2)
{
    dictionary[list[index]] = list[index + 1];
}
```

You definitely *can* do it with LINQ, but it would be more complicated - I love using LINQ when it makes things simpler, but sometimes it's just not a great fit.

(Obviously you can wrap that up into an extension method.)

Note that you can use `dictionary.Add(list[index], list[index + 1])` to throw an exception if there are duplicate keys - the above code will silently use the *last* occurrence of a particular key.

Comment: +1 for daring to favor an old-school longhand method over cute, but less readable, code.

Comment: `dictionary.Add(...)` instead of `dictionary[...] = ...` has the advantage of throwing an appropriate exception when keys are duplicated.

Comment: @TomBlodget: True. Will add a note.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a range that is half the length of the list, and `ToDictionary` to create the dictionary from items from the list:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
  Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count / 2)
  .ToDictionary(i => list[i * 2], i => list[i * 2 + 1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ and `GroupBy` version:

```
var dict = source.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                 .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2)
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.First().s, g => g.Last().s);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need LINQ - you can Zip list to itself first:

```
var result = list.Where((item, id) => id % 2 == 0)
     .Zip (list.Where((item, id) => id % 2 == 1), 
          (key, value) => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(key, value))
     .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```